# How to get data attribute from radio button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the data-price value from radio button which is checked. I tried something like that:

```
<input type="radio" name="vehicletype" id="vehicletype" value="{{$vehicletypeData->id}}" data-price="{{$vehicletypeData->km_rate}}" required="">


var vehicleTyp=document.getElementById("vehicletype");
                var vetselindx=vehicleTyp.options[vehicleTyp.selectedIndex];
                var prikm=vetselindx.getAttribute("data-price");
```

But this does not work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: is it `{{$vehicletypeData->id}}` Laravel ?

Comment: @RishiRaut yah Sir

Comment: Try console.log(vehicleTyp.dataset.price);

Comment: You have only shown one radio button, but would I be correct in thinking that you are (mistakenly) setting the same `id` attribute on all the radio buttons in the set, then trying to use `.options` - which is for `<select>` elements - to get the chosen one?

Comment: @lakshay Uncaught reference error: `$` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> document.getElementById("vehicletype");
> ```

This gets the element with that id. The single element with that id. Multiple elements in a document cannot share an id.

> ```
> vehicleTyp.options
> ```

Select elements have options. Radio buttons do not.

---

To find the checked element you should:

- Get all the radio buttons. Consider `getElementsByName`
- Loop over them until you find one where the `checked` property is true

---

Once you have found the element you are looking for you can use `getAttribute("data-price");` or [the `dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: You can also use `document.querySelector("[name=vehicletype]:checked")` to directly get the selected radio button. This will return `null` if none of them have been selected yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the custom `data-` attributes of an element like so:

```
const el = document.getElementById("vehicletype");
const price = el.dataset.price;
```

For more information see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on using data attributes.

**Note:** If you have a second dash in the attribute name e.g. `data-price-new` the `dataset` object property will reflect this in camelcase. `dataset.priceNew`

Comment: While this is true, it does not do anything to address the issue in the question. In fact, `elem.getAttribute("data-price")` is the only bit of code in the question that's actually working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Working code, using getElementsByName

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-type="one-time" name="payment-radio-btn" value="200" id="flexRadioDefault1" checked />One Time

<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-type="two-time" name="payment-radio-btn" value="300" id="flexRadioDefault1"/>Two time

<p> <button  onClick="performAction()">Submit</button> </p>



function performAction(){
 var amount = 0;
var type = '';

 var radios = document.getElementsByName('payment-radio-btn');
    for (var radio of radios) {
            if (radio.checked) {
                amount = radio.value;
                type = radio.getAttribute("data-type");
               
        }
  }
alert(type) 
}
```

[Codepen-link](https://codepen.io/john-godstime/pen/mdBqgEP)